# Is it possible to use Jupyter Tooltip (shift+tab) on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I know I can hover the cursor over the function, but this shows the docs in a clumsy way: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cufL1.png).

Is it possible to make it just like the Jupyter tooltip?

Comment: what does the "Jupyter tooltip" look like? can you also add code for a [mre] and show screenshots corresponding to it in VS Code and in whatever you are comparing it to?

Answer (score 1):

On macbook it's cmd + shift + space

Comment: This can be remapped in vscode with the Trigger Parameter Hints command in Keyboard Shortcuts